# Xcode: Advice on working with xcassets

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I have an existing project where I have previously dragged and dropped many images into Xcode and then organised them according to their names. So, for example, I have folder called Intro that has images named intro_01, intro_02,... and another folder called Navigation that has images such as navigation_icon, navigation_back, etc.
I recently thought of using .xcassets instead and I was wondering how I should organise the images? Should I have an Intro.xcassets with intro_01, intro_02, etc inside and a Navigation.xcassets with navigation_icon, navigation_back, etc. or should I create one Images.xcassets and dump all the images in there?

What are the best practices? I have tried looking on the internet for a solution for this problem but haven't found anything that I understand so I was wondering if someone could please help me?

Thanks in advance for your replies! Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One image.xcassets with all images. Just name them with a prefix and search on that prefix as needed.

Comment: Okay great. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: This is just one person's opinion. This answer isn't necessarily a "best practice".

Comment: You can also create folders inside of asset libraries

Comment: @rmaddy that's true.
I have over 100 images so I definitely need a better way to organise them and call and set images in code.
Edit: As dan said, I think I'll use one image.xcassets and create folders inside them.

Thanks for your inputs!